# Error with jasmine node module in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm receiving the following error,

- I've tried changing my version of typescript, but this doesn't fix
  the issue.
- I've tried running `npm update --save` and still nothing
  works.

  ERROR in [default] /Users/gdayton/Documents/auction/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:37 
  A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.

  ERROR in [default] /Users/gdayton/Documents/auction/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:45 
  Cannot find name 'keyof'.

  ERROR in [default] /Users/gdayton/Documents/auction/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:51 
  '=' expected.

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "auction2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run a quick update for all packages and update the package.json file with updated versions, Follow these steps

1. Delete the **node_modules** folder.
2. Delete npm-cache from C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming
3. Open command prompt and navigate to root folder of your application.
4. Check for the updates in npm packages using the command

   ```
   npm-check-updates -u
   ```
5. Update all the packages and modify your package.json to current version using the command

   ```
   npm update --save
   ```

Also, update the npm packages globally using the command

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Hope this must fix your problem, if not let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR in [default] /Users/gdayton/Documents/auction/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:45 Cannot find name 'keyof'.

`keyof` was introduced in [Typescript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html), and in your `package.json` I see `Typescript 2.0.2`.  I know you mentioned you upgraded Typescript, but maybe an even more recent version is needed.

Comment: Hey, I updated Typescript to 2.2.1, and now the following error occurs: `ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exclude' of undefined
    at applyDefaults (/Users/gdayton/Documents/auction2/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/instance.ts:266:72)...` Am I correct in assuming that `awesome-typescript-loader` requires an older version of Typescript?

Comment: Yeah, there might be a mismatch there on the loader and the typescript version.  This might be tricky, as it's possible there's no compatible configuration across your packages -- sounds like you might have to upgrade or downgrade one of those packages to get an acceptable version for everything.